# Oracle 11g how to store multi values to one column but get ok performance

Tags: arrays, oracle, performance, oracle11g, regexp-substr

[image: Table definition]

Hi，

My database is Oracle11g. For some reason, I need to store one or several values in column1. In this case I use '||' as a delimiter.  So the sql query is trying to answer, e.g. if value 310-G01-000-000-000 in column1?

I want a solution, for Oracle 11g, to enhance the query performance? I know that PostgreSQL column can store an array, and there is index for array. But for Oracle, I don't know.

On of my thought is using REGEXP_SUBSTR to generate a list, and use function index on REGEXP_SUBSTR may work?

Please let me know the best practice to store multi values to one column and the way to query it quickly?

Thanks a lot
J

Comment: This is a denormalized database design, that could be beneficial for a few read-only queries, but quite detrimental for the rest of queries (when applying changes). Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Yes，only for query beneficial

Comment: I have made some experiments.
create table testtable(id integer primary key, column1 varchar2(200));
insert into testtable （id,column1) values(123,'310-G01-000-000-000,310-G04-000-000-000,310-G04-000-000-001');
insert into testtable （id,column1) values(456,'310-G01-000-000-000');
select id from (SELECT
  id,REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1,'[^,]+',1,level)  region 
  FROM testtable connect by level <= (REGEXP_COUNT(column1,'\,')+1)) where region = '310-G01-000-000-000' ;then I create a function index:
CREATE INDEX index1 ON testtable(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column1,'[^,]+',1) );
The index seems doesnt help

Comment: I was thinking about this problem. With a normalizes the design (one value per row) the search would be really fast. Without it it's not easy for the engine to index it.

Comment: Use [Nested Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99929). Oracle provides [various functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/operators006.htm#SQLRF0032) for them, they are much easier and have better performance than regular expressions.

Comment: no, we don't want normalize it.There are  N:N relationships, but I don't want to create  relationship tables because there are so many other tables like testtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want performance then don't store delimited values in a column.

If you cannot avoid it then just use simple string functions (which are an order of magnitude faster than regular expressions) to check if there is a sub-string match:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_table
WHERE  '||' || column1 || '||' LIKE '%||' || :search_value || '||%';
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_table
WHERE  INSTR('||' || column1 || '||', '||' || :search_value || '||') > 0;
```

---

#### However

You could use a nested table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(19);

CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id      VARCHAR2(10),
  column1 string_list
) NESTED TABLE column1 STORE AS test_table__column1;
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (
  id,
  column1
) VALUES (
  'abc',
  string_list('310-G01-000-000-000', '310-G04-000-000-000','310-G04-000-000-001')
);
```

and to find the value use the `MEMBER OF` collection operator:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   test_table
WHERE  '310-G01-000-000-000' MEMBER OF column1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d12c86fea201490eac029c49ff446ebe)*

Comment: Hi MTO,

Thank you!  I test your code , all good. So the nested table must have better performance than delimited values ，correct? 

In real world, the test_table already exists and it has 6 millions records. Do I have to recreate it using the ’create table‘ statement you provided , or can I use  'Alter table add column column1' sort of statement? I don't know the specific syntax, can you please tell me？

Also, do I need to create any index for the column1?

Thanks

Comment: I create index for the nested table, I will try to test if the index help.
create or replace type obj as object ( column1_t varchar2(100));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_list AS TABLE OF obj;
CREATE  TABLE test_table ( id      VARCHAR2(10), column1 string_list
) NESTED TABLE column1 STORE AS test_table__column1;
INSERT INTO test_table ( id, column1) VALUES ('abc',
  string_list(obj('310-G01-000-000-000'),obj('310-G04-000-000-000'),obj('310-G04-000-000-001'))
);
create  index index1 on test_table__column1 (column1_t);

Comment: @TonyRen It is in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#i2192749) `ALTER TABLE test_table ADD ( column1 string_list ) NESTED TABLE column1 STORE AS test_table__column1;` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f64974a4f5c20a7450da5a1159cdf61)